# Issue with testing middleware in a nodejs express typescript project

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I have been following `https://github.com/goldbergyoni/nodebestpractices` to learn more about nodejs best practices.

I have the following middleware that I implemented:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import { BAD_REQUEST_ERROR_TYPES } from "../constants";
import { BadRequestError } from "./../error-handling";

const isAccountActive = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  if (req.session?.user?.isEmailVerified) {
    next();
  } else {
    next(new BadRequestError(BAD_REQUEST_ERROR_TYPES.ACCOUNT_NOT_ACTIVE));
  }
};

export default isAccountActive;
```

This is the test that I wrote for it:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
// @ts-nocheck

import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { BAD_REQUEST_ERROR_TYPES } from "../constants";
import { BadRequestError } from "../error-handling";
import isAccountActive from "./isAccountActive";

describe("isAccountActive Middleware", () => {
  describe("Recieving a request", () => {
    test("When the request has a userUUID set in the session, it calls the next function without throwing a Bad Request Account Not Active error", async () => {
      // Arrange
      const req = {
        method: "GET",
        url: "/user/42",
        session: {
          user: {
            userUUID: "some-string",
          },
        },
      } as unknown as Request;
      const res = jest.fn as unknown as Response;
      const next = jest.fn;
      // Act
      await isAccountActive(req, res, next);
      // Assert
      expect(next).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(next).toBeCalledWith(
        new BadRequestError(BAD_REQUEST_ERROR_TYPES.ACCOUNT_NOT_ACTIVE)
      );
    });
  });
});
```

That is implementation number 3 for that test. I also tried using `sinon`, and `node-mocks-http`.

When I run the test command, I get the following error regardless of any implementation:

[image]

My app builds and runs fine; so I am not quite sure why jest would be throwing this error when the actuall server code itself is being compiled and run without any issues.

For reference, my `config.ts`:

```
import { isFullRedisURL } from "./helpers";
import { z } from "zod";
import { REDIS_URL_ERROR } from "./constants";
import { StartupError } from "./error-handling";

const input = {
  environment: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  basePort: process.env.BASE_PORT,
  redisUrl: process.env.REDIS_URL,
  redisPassword: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
  databaseUrl: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  sessionSecret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
};

const configSchema = z.object({
  environment: z.string(),
  basePort: z.coerce.number().positive().int(),
  redisUrl: z
    .string()
    .refine((val) => isFullRedisURL(val), { message: REDIS_URL_ERROR }),
  redisPassword: z.string(),
  databaseUrl: z.string(),
  sessionSecret: z.string().min(8),
});

let parsedInput;

try {
  parsedInput = configSchema.parse(input);
} catch (e) {
  throw new StartupError("Config validation error", e);
}

export const config = parsedInput;

export type Config = z.infer<typeof configSchema>;
```

my `error-handling/error-handling-middleware.ts`

```
import { COMMON_ERRORS, STATUS_CODES } from "../constants";
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import errorHandler from "./errorHandler";
import { config } from "../config";

const errorHandlingMiddleware = async (
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  error: any,
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  if (error && typeof error === "object") {
    if (error.isTrusted === undefined || error.isTrusted === null) {
      error.isTrusted = true; // Error during a specific request is usually not fatal and should not lead to process exit
    }
  }

  errorHandler.handleError(error);

  const { environment } = config;

  const result = {
    status: error?.httpStatus || STATUS_CODES.InternalServerError,
    name: error?.name || COMMON_ERRORS.InternalServerError,
    message: error?.message || "Sorry, something went wrong.",
    details: error?.details,
    stacktrace: environment === "development" ? error?.stacktrace : undefined,
  };

  res
    .status(error?.httpStatus || STATUS_CODES.InternalServerError)
    .send(result);
};

export default errorHandlingMiddleware;
```

the `StartupError` class:

```
import { FieldError } from "__shared/types";
import {
  COMMON_ERRORS,
  BAD_REQUEST_ERROR_MESSAGES,
  BAD_REQUEST_ERROR_TYPES,
  STATUS_CODES,
} from "../constants";

export class ApplicationError extends Error {
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public message: string,
    public httpStatus: STATUS_CODES = STATUS_CODES.InternalServerError,
    public isTrusted: boolean = true,
    public isOperational: boolean = true,
    public details?: FieldError[],
    public stacktrace?: unknown
  ) {
    super(message); // 'Error' breaks prototype chain here
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new.target.prototype); // restore prototype chain

    this.name = name;
    this.httpStatus = httpStatus;
    this.isOperational = isOperational;
    this.isTrusted = isTrusted;
    this.details = details;
    this.stacktrace = stacktrace;

    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  }
}

export class BadRequestError extends ApplicationError {
  constructor(type: keyof typeof BAD_REQUEST_ERROR_TYPES) {
    super(
      COMMON_ERRORS.BadRequestError,
      BAD_REQUEST_ERROR_MESSAGES[type],
      STATUS_CODES.BadRequest,
      true,
      true
    );
  }
}

export class StartupError extends ApplicationError {
  constructor(reason: string, error: unknown) {
    super(
      COMMON_ERRORS.StartupError,
      `Start up failed: (${reason}) `,
      STATUS_CODES.InternalServerError,
      false,
      true,
      undefined,
      error
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the top parts of the test file as well? That seems to be where the error is happening.

Comment: @DavidR, I updated the code for the test file to include the top part

Comment: when i replace my `config.ts` error with this: 
```
  // throw new StartupError("Config validation error", e);
  throw new Error("Config validation error" + e);
```

it seems to be happy but throws a new error where it says my environment variables are not set

i cant quite work out why jest isnt happy with my StartupError class when nodejs is fine with it and also why it seems to be wanting to basically run the express server in the background even though my test is for the middleware function only. will i have to test the api endpoints directly if i want to test out the middleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing the following:
create `src\server\dotenv-config.js`

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: "../../.env",
});
```

Update my `src\server\server-jest-config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/dotenv-config.js"],
  // An array of file extensions your modules use
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "js", , "json", "node"],

  // A list of paths to directories that Jest should use to search for files in
  roots: ["<rootDir>"],

  // The test environment that will be used for testing
  testEnvironment: "node",

  // Options that will be passed to the testEnvironment
  // testEnvironmentOptions: {},

  // Adds a location field to test results
  // testLocationInResults: false,

  // test files should contain `test`
  testRegex: "((\\.|/)(test))\\.ts?$",

  // A map from regular expressions to paths to transformers
  // Jest transformations -- this adds support for TypeScript
  // using ts-jest
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.ts?$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2|svg)$":
      "jest-transform-stub",
  },

  modulePathIgnorePatterns: [
    "<rootDir>/../../node_modules",
    "<rootDir>/../../dist",
  ],
};
```

my test script

```
    "server:test": "cd src/server && jest --config ./server-jest-config.js"
```

Finally for my test I had to turn the next function into a mock function

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { BAD_REQUEST_ERROR_TYPES } from "../constants";
import { BadRequestError } from "../error-handling";
import isAccountActive from "./isAccountActive";

describe("isAccountActive Middleware", () => {
  describe("Recieving a request", () => {
    test("When the request has a userUUID set in the session, it calls the next function without throwing a Bad Request Account Not Active error", async () => {
      // Arrange
      const req = {
        method: "GET",
        url: "/user/42",
        session: {
          user: {
            userUUID: "some-string",
          },
        },
      } as unknown as Request;
      const res = jest.fn as unknown as Response;
      const next = jest.fn((e) => console.log(e));
      // Act
      await isAccountActive(req, res, next);
      // Assert
      expect(next).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(next).toBeCalledWith(
        new BadRequestError(BAD_REQUEST_ERROR_TYPES.ACCOUNT_NOT_ACTIVE)
      );
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: FYI: i have a client and server folder in my src; and my env file lives in the server folder.